# What kind of isomerism does Ni(PPh3)2Cl2 have and what is their IUPAC name?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction

I know that there are 2 isomers that $\ce{Ni(PPh3)2Cl2}$ have and they exist in equilibrium. I am tempted to name them cis- and trans- but it does not sound right.

Comment: Given that one isomer is tetrahedral and one is square planar, cis and trans would not be correct as there is no cis/trans in a tetrahedron. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)nickel(II)

Comment: Answer for the question is  here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115553/why-is-nipph%e2%82%83%e2%82%82cl%e2%82%82-tetrahedral/115563#115563..One of the structures is square planar ,while the other is  tetrahedral.The square planar complex can both be cis and trans.

Answer (score 2):

A metal phosphine complex, dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)nickel(II) exists in two isomeric forms (blue and red) based on how you prepared it ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)nickel(II))). The blue isomer, which is *paramagnetic* can be prepared by treating hydrated nickel chloride ($\ce{NiCl2.6H2O}$) with triphenylphosphine in alcohols or glacial acetic acid. When allowed to crystallize from chlorinated solvents (*e.g.*, dicloroethane (Ref.1), dicloromethane (Ref.2)), the tetrahedral isomer converts to the square planar red isomer, which is *trans* and *diamagnetic*:

[image: Crystal Structure]

**References:**

1. Benedetto Corain, Bruno Longato, Roberto Angeletti, Giovanni Valle, “*trans*-[Dichlorobis(triphenylphosphine)nickel(II)]•$\ce{(C2H4Cl2)2}$: a clathrate of the allogon of venanzi's tetrahedral complex,” *Inorganica Chimica Acta* **1985**, *104(1)*, 15–18 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-1693(00)83780-9).
2. A. S. Batsanov,  J. A. K. Howard, “*trans*-Di­chloro­bis­(tri­phenyl­phosphine)­nickel(II) bis­(di­chloro­methane) solvate: redetermination at $\pu{120 K}$,” *Acta Cryst.* **2001**, *E57*, m308–m309 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600536801008741).